# Is it possible to use relative path in the DataBaseDirectory Parameter in TM1s.cfg?

Tags: cube, cognos-tm1

I am configuring a TM1 Server instance per TM1s.cfg file.

The Parameter [DataBaseDirectory](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS9RXT_10.2.2/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.tm1_inst.10.2.2.doc/c_databasedirectory_bv5467.html#DataBaseDirectory_BV5467) specifies the location of the relevant cube data. Is it possible to specify a path in a relative manner or does it have to be absolute? If it is possible, what is the accepted syntax? The docs do not specify anything about it.

Paths relative to current dir works, just starts with a "/" . But it seems as navigating upwards with "../" doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply specify the folder name. In the example below, I'm using the relative path for the DataBaseDirectory parameter and the absolute one the LogginDirectory.

```
DataBaseDirectory=DataFiles
LoggingDirectory=C:\TM1Data\TM1_Demo\Logfiles
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to navigate upwards in relation to the current dir?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand ?

Comment: I mean a way to navigate one level up from the current directory. Like ../ or similar.

Comment: did you try relative path?

Comment: relative to current dir works, just starts with a "/" . But it seems as navigating upwards with "../" doesnt work.